# How to make Java program exit after a couple of seconds

Tags: java, system, exit, seconds

Is there anyway I can exit a java program after a couple of seconds e.g. 5 seconds.

I know you can quit the java program using:

```
System.exit(0);
```

But I'm not sure whether the 0 stands for seconds since this code:

```
System.exit(10);
```

also exits instantly

Comment: This is interesting, but why on earth would you exit from a running VM?

Comment: 0 `does not stand for seconds`.  In System.exit(X), X is the exit code from your program (what it will report to the calling shell), it has nothing to do with time.

Comment: @Eugene I'm trying to create a game in which you have to answer math questions quickly.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

System.exit(0) specifies the exit error code of the program.

you can put it on a timer and schedule the task

```
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.Timer;
import java.util.TimerTask;

public class TimedExit {
Timer timer = new Timer();
TimerTask exitApp = new TimerTask() {
public void run() {
    System.exit(0);
    }
};

public TimedExit() {
timer.schedule(exitApp, new Date(System.currentTimeMillis()+5*1000));
    }

}
```

and then you can just called TimedExit()

Comment: Thanks, I used this idea and updated it to the java 8 way. It is now a one-liner: Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor().schedule(() -> System.exit(0), 60, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

Answer (score 8):

You can invoke `Thread.sleep()` just before you exit your program:

```
// Your code goes here.

try 
{
   Thread.sleep(5000);
} 
catch (InterruptedException e) 
{
   // log the exception.
}

System.exit(0);
```

Comment: this could fail if there is a security check enabled

Comment: @Eugene yes, it might. can you eloborate and provide a solution for that case?

Answer (score 1):

From [System.exit(int)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#exit%28int%29) method documentation:

> Terminates the currently running Java Virtual Machine. The argument
>   serves as a status code; by convention, a nonzero status code
>   indicates abnormal termination.

If you need to execute something during the time waiting for exit, you could create a control thread, that will just wait for the right time to perform the exit like this:

```
public class ExitFewMiliseconds {

    public static void main(String args[]) {

        new Thread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(100);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                System.exit(0);
            }
        }).start();

        while (true) {
            System.out.println("I'm doing something");
        }
    }

}
```

If nothing shall be executing while waiting for exit, you could simply use a [Thread.sleep(ms)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#sleep%28long%29)

Answer (score 0):

The 0 you pass into System.exit(0) has nothing to do with how long it will wait before exiting.  [Javadocs are your friend](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#exit%28int%29).  From the javadoc:

> The argument serves as a status code; by convention, a nonzero status
>   code indicates abnormal termination.

Other answers already cover how to wait 5 seconds before exiting if you really need to do that.

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.util.Timer;
import java.util.TimerTask;

/**
 * Simple demo that uses java.util.Timer to schedule a task 
 * to execute once 5 seconds have passed.
 */
class Reminder {

    Timer timer;

    public Reminder(int seconds) {
        timer = new Timer();
        timer.schedule(new RemindTask(), seconds * 1000);
    }

    class RemindTask extends TimerTask {
        public void run() {
            System.out.format("Time's up!%n");
            System.exit();
            timer.cancel(); //Terminate the timer thread
        }
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        new Reminder(10);
        System.out.format("Task scheduled.%n");
    }
}
```

In this way you can use the Timer class and exit the system after a particular time interval