# Schedule top / terminate a Java program on a specific time

Tags: java, timer

Is there any way to schedule to stop or terminate a java program on a specific time. I am using **java.util.timer**. For example at 10pm. I know how to schedule start a java program on a specific time. Problem is I cannot figure out a way to terminate a program.

Comment: System.exit(1) stops a java program. But i don't know if it is the best way...

Comment: "I know how to schedule start a java program on a specific time" How about using the same method to schedule a `kill -SIGTERM` at the desired time?

Comment: I want to know how to schedule that..for ex stop at 10pm.. my bad i didn't mention it in the question. I updated my question.sorry

Comment: You want to stop a "remote" Java application, and not your application?

Comment: Calendar today = Calendar.getInstance();
        today.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 18);//set to 18 which is 6:00PM in 24 HRs
        today.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 00);
        today.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
// every night at 2am you run your task
        Timer timer = new Timer();
        timer.schedule(

, today.getTime());   

class CloseApp implements Runnable{
public void run(){
System.exit(0);
}}}

Comment: or use cron job in linux 00 18 * * * /etc/init.d/application stop

Comment: @benjamin ... stop my application

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use TimerTask to do that, here is an example:

```
  import java.util.Date;
import java.util.Timer;
import java.util.TimerTask;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

public class StopApp {
Timer timer = new Timer();
TimerTask StopApp = new TimerTask() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        System.exit(0);
    }
};
public StopApp() {

//timer.schedule(exitApp, getDateDiff(new Date("get the actual time"), new Date("get the time you want to stop your app"), TimeUnit.SECONDS));
    //Example
    timer.schedule(StopApp, new Date(System.currentTimeMillis()+2*1000));//Exits after 2 sec of starting the app

while(true)

    System.out.println("The App still turn");
}

public static Date getDateDiff(Date date1, Date date2, TimeUnit timeUnit) {
    long diffInMillies = date2.getTime() - date1.getTime();
    Date date=new Date(diffInMillies);

    return date;//timeUnit.convert(diffInMillies,TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
}

public static void main(String[] args) {

    new StopApp();

}
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can create a background thread (in order to not block UI) and inside you can check current hour/minutes/day

```java
GregorianCalendar calendar = new GregorianCalendar (); // creates a new calendar instance 
calendar.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY); // gets hour in 24h format
calendar.get(Calendar.HOUR);        // gets hour in 12h format
calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH);       // gets month number, NOTE this is zero based!
Thread.sleep(60000)                 //sleep 60seconds

if(<rightTime>)
    System.exit(0);
```

See also https://stackoverflow.com/a/907207/6726261

Answer (score 0):

Check this doc: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#exit(int).
`System.exit(0);` can do what you want.

Comment: I want to know how to schedule that..for ex stop at 10pm.. my bad i didn't mention it in the question. I updated my question.sorry

Comment: D.Madu said that he was using java.util.timer so i think that he already know how to schedule a task (Sytem.exit(0) in this case).

Comment: D.Madu check the answer of nate_weldon to this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15747277/how-to-make-java-program-exit-after-a-couple-of-seconds. It may help you.

Answer (score 0):

To stop your program use: `System.exit(0);`
More info [here](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/lang/system_exit.htm)

Comment: You are missing the _on a specific time_ part of the question

Comment: @AxelH `I know how to schedule start a java program on a specific time. Problem is I cannot figure out a way to terminate a program.`

Comment: I want to know how to schedule that..for ex stop at 10pm.. my bad i didn't mention it in the question. I updated my question.sorry

Answer (score 0):

You could use [procrun](http://www.apache.org/dist/commons/daemon/binaries/windows/), which will create a service which will run your java application. Then you can schedule start and stop of your service.

You should read the [docs of procrun](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-daemon/procrun.html) which explain how to configure your service.

The easier way to do this is just to run `prunsrv //IS//my_service_name` which creates the service, then you execute  `prunmngr //ES//my_service_name` which will open a service configuration dialog where you can set up all service parameters.

Your application will need a public static method to call which will be used by procrun to stop your application.

Another option is to read from a stream and wait for some input, when input is read you stop the application.

This stream could be a socket or a file, then when you want to stop your app, you just schedule another application to write on that stream.